# Using Sencha Architect, how do you make the Scroll Indicators show permanently?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

Apparently, there is a solution to making the scroll bar always appear in Sencha Touch. You just add the following to a css file:

```
.x-scroll-indicator {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

My question is where/how do I accomplish this using Sencha Architect?

What I've tried:
I created a CSS Resource file using the Project Inspector and pasted the CSS code above but the scroll bar still disappears.

I've gotten advice that the CSS code should be pasted in the app.json file. However, Sencha Architect users know that the file doesn't exist - it only appears when the app is packaged.

Comment: CSS code should be pasted in the app.css ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may help you
Always show scroll indicators in formpanel
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255762-Always-show-scroll-indicators-in-formpanel